# Facebook developer console not recognizing platform

Tags: ios, facebook, publishing, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to switch from development to production (live) for my IOS app on facebook developer console. whenever i attempt to do so i get the error displayed in image attached. Yes, i have added the IOS platform with my bundle id in the basic section and there is a pretty green tick next to IOS in advanced settings. any suggestions? Is this perhaps a bug on facebooks side?

[image: facebook error message]